# How to specify a jps name running a jar?

Tags: java, scala, jar

I execute the following command to run my jar:

```
java -cp test.jar com.mycomp.Test
```

jps

```
-bash-4.2$ jps
20240 Test
```

I would like to specify a name for jps. Something like:

```
java -cp test.jar com.mycomp.Test -appName Test-dev
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Probably not: _"With no options, jps will list each Java application's lvmid followed by the short form of the application's class name or jar file name. The short form of the class name or JAR file name omits the class's package information or the JAR files path information."_ from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jps.html